# C++: FStream thinks it has reached EOF of binary file

Tags: c++, binary, fstream, eof

I'm trying to read a binary file with the following format:

-64 bit integer

-3276 32-bit floats

-(Repeat last 2 lines until eof)

This is the block where I interpret the file:

```
ifstream bbrFile;
ofstream csvFile;

bbrFile.open(inFilename);
csvFile.open(dataFilename);
//yes I did actually check to make sure that the files had opened. 
//I omitted it here for brevity

long long int time;
float point;
while (bbrFile)
{
    bbrFile.read((char*)&time, sizeof(time));
    csvFile << time;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3276; i++) {
                bbrFile.read((char*)&point, sizeof(point));
                csvFile << ',' << point;
    }
    csvFile << "\n";
}
```

So far, my code is working fine, except that it thinks it's reached the end of file after reading in about 53 floats, and then just outputs the last float it read until the 'for' loop ends. I've tried using fread and FILE* instead of read and fstream, and gotten identical results. I've also tried replacing

```
while (bbrFile)
```

with

```
while (!bbrFile.eof())
```

To no avail.

Since the binary file is about 12 megabytes, I'm somewhat as a loss as to why it stops reading here.

Comment: What is `trace`?  That seems pretty important here.

Comment: it's an error I made while copying this from my own code. `trace` should read `point`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To read the file as a binary file, you should add `binary` to the file mode:

```
bbrFile.open(inFilename, ios::binary);
```

otherwise it will be read as a text file, and some codes could be interpreted as an end-of-file mark.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you for the help.